# No Sonarqube scanner configuration in Jenkins 2.7.1

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, jenkins-plugins, sonarqube-scan

I can't find the SonarQube Scanner configuration inside Jenkins Administration. 
After installing the SonarQube Plugin, I've got the "SonarQube servers" section but not the "SonarQube Scanner" section as described in the documentation : http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Jenkins

Did I miss something ?

Versions :

- Jenkins 2.7.1
- SonarQube Plugin 2.4.4
- SonarQube Server 5.6

I tried on latest Jenkins 2 Version (2.7.2), same result.
It works on latest Jenkins 1 Version (1.651.3)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like the documentation still refers to old versions of Jenkins. In latest versions the `SonarQube Scanner` section hides under *Manage Jenkins* - *Global Tool Configuration*.

Comment: You sir, are a life saver !